# Using Crypto++ to Verify Windows Hello public key

Tags: c++, crypto++, c++-winrt, windows-hello

I am attempting to take a public key generated from Windows Hello and Verify the signature with the CryptoPP library.  One of the issues is according to Windows Hello documentation a dev does not have access to private keys, so I need to use the signature given to me from Windows Hello (RequestSignAsync()) as well as the public key.
Is this possible?

I have created a WinRT version of a Windows Hello interface based on this C# sample:
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/MicrosoftPassport

I have my reasons for not wanting to us the server code that is provided in the example, so I am attempting to verify signature with Crypto++.

Then sending the signature and public key to this CryptoPP setup:

```
   CryptoPP::RSA::PublicKey keyPublic;

   keyPublic.Load(CryptoPP::StringSource(pubkey, true, new CryptoPP::Base64Decoder()).Ref() );

   CryptoPP::RSASS<CryptoPP::PKCS1v15, CryptoPP::SHA256>::Verifier verifier(keyPublic);

   bool bSignatureVerified = false;
   std::string sigdata;

   CryptoPP::StringSource ss(sig,true,
           new CryptoPP::Base64Decoder(
             new CryptoPP::StringSink(sigdata)
           )); // Base64Decoder

   CryptoPP::StringSource ss2(sigdata, true,
                              new CryptoPP::SignatureVerificationFilter(
                                verifier,
                                new CryptoPP::ArraySink((CryptoPP::byte*)&bSignatureVerified,
                                sizeof(bSignatureVerified)
                                )
                              )
   );

   if(!bSignatureVerified)
   {
      return -2; //signed message not valid
   }
   else
   {
      return 0;
   }
```

The public key and signature are being sent over from a Windows Hello interface. I am getting a failed verification here for some reason.

Here is the Windows Hello documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/microsoft-passport

Seems to match with my logic for Crypto++ (PKCS1v1.5, SHA256,ASN.1-encoded) but I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like was not understanding that I needed to pass the signature AND the message.

This seemed to work:

```
   CryptoPP::StringSource ss(sig,true,
           new CryptoPP::Base64Decoder(
             new CryptoPP::StringSink(sigdata)
           )); // Base64Decoder

   CryptoPP::StringSource ssmsg(msg,true,
           new CryptoPP::Base64Decoder(
             new CryptoPP::StringSink(msgdata)
           )); // Base64Decoder

   CryptoPP::StringSource ss2(sigdata+msgdata, true,
                              new CryptoPP::SignatureVerificationFilter(
                                verifier,
                                new CryptoPP::ArraySink((CryptoPP::byte*)&bSignatureVerified,
                                sizeof(bSignatureVerified)
                                )
                              )
   );
```